# Send a downloadable CSV as response in Next.js

Tags: node.js, express, next.js, httpresponse, next.js13

With the following code, I can get a downloadable file when requested.

```js
const csv = converter.json2csv(data);
return new Response(csv, {
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'text/csv',
    'Content-Disposition': 'attachment',
  }
});
```

But the downloaded file name is "download.csv". How do I make it download with my desired file name? E.g. "data.csv"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the link they click to download the file, you can set the HTML5 [download attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download). This will allow you to set a default file name.

```html
<a href="path/to/file" download="renamed.txt">Download</a>
```

Note that the `download` attribute only works for [same origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) urls